# Software/Python library for Ontology building from Excel

Tags: python, data-visualization, microsoft-excel

I'm tasked with reading certain parts of an extensive excel of building equipment and mapping it into an ontology. The specific part that needs to be mapped are a variety of Air Handling Units (AHU) or similar equipment and their internal components.
The excel sometimes adheres to the haystack format, but not always.

The candidates I found so far are: BrickSchema, Pylode, Plaster, possibly combined with RDFLib and OWL. My knowledge of these library is still very limited, so I'm having trouble evaluating them.

Which library would you recommend for the task? Are there any better suited libraries or even programs?

Brick has a sample plan of something similar of what I need on their website. However what I'd need is a more zoomed in version. The same plan, but for the internal parts and connections of AHU1A. Is the library capable of this level?

[image: Sample Image from Brick]

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that [Brick](https://brickschema.org/) seems to be the best option. It's exact focus is translating this kind of data into Brick ontologies . For the necessary data normalization the tools Plaster and [OpenRefine](https://openrefine.org/)  options. Both solutions are also supported by Brick.
Unfortunately the Plaster tool was discontinued and the OpenRefine [reconciliation API](https://github.com/BrickSchema/reconciliation-api) is not completely mature yet. In addition the Data must also converted into bricks using [brickify](https://brickschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/brickify/index.html).

Comment: Adding a link would improve this answer.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, to make it clear to others who read this question in future